# python : how do I perform a specific df operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my original Q

[python how do I perform the below operation in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139983/python-how-do-i-perform-the-below-operation-in-dataframe/65140307?noredirect=1#comment115162548_65140307)

I want to check how do I start with the output and get the original df back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for numbers and strings to 2 new columns and then reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), last some data processing to match input:

```
df[['Year','col']] = df['Year'].str.extract('(\d+)([A-Z])')
df = (df.pivot('Year','col','Val')
        .rename(columns={'A':'Tval1','B':'Tval2'})
        .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1))
df['Year'] +='A'
print (df)
  Year  Tval1  Tval2
0   1A      1     34
1   2A      9     56
2   3A      8     67
3   4A      1     78
4   5A      6     89
```

Comment: perfect! liked that! ( looks like I cant accept your solution for another 12 mins!)